# How do I change the order and number of slices in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, slices

I have an old manuscript that is scanned as 4 pages per A4, I need to slice it down to 4 separate pages, each page as a single file.
I used actions in Photoshop to separate every two A4 into two files, a top and bottom ones with 2 pages in each of them.
Now, since the scan is not very accurate, I need to manually slice these images (the ones I get from my previous step) into two separate pages, and to save time I decided to use the slice tool to slice each image into two slices, then export them for web so I get two separate image files in a single step.

The problem is that the manuscript is written in Arabic, so the direction is from right to left. Photoshop, by default, recognizes slice that starts from the very top left corner as slice #1, and other slices as #2 and/or #3. According to this order of slices the exported files will take their names, and due to that I will have page no. 2 as no. 1, and page no. 2 as no.1!

I tried to change the point of origin of the ruler, but with no luck!

How can I make Photoshop flip the document direction so it considers the top right corner as the beginning instead of the top left corner?
Or is there any way to change the order of slices?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this is what I have worked out.

Slices will automatically be ordered from left to right yes but the image doesnt have to be upright.

So for a film reel example where I want columns and slices going vertically down then right ...

Rotate the image.  So my picture is now on its side and the slices run along the length meaning when I cut them it will have cut down along the image then across.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the **Slice Select Tool** you can change the slice name clicking the **Edit Slice Options**. When saving, each slice will be saved following the name order you have put.

[image]

[image]